# autopopulate Document properties

Tags: 2013, document-info-panel

Is there a way to autopopulate document properties?
I've read things about creating a list and a document library and use a workflow but this is not the approach i'm looking for (this only works for Word, I think), also I think i cannot use infopath because infopath doesn't work in O365.

Can you help me to get my way on this road?

Comment: Are you talking something like the document quick part?

Comment: Or are you talking about something like column default values?

Comment: Something like the quick part. Let me explain myself: we have a form that fills some fields automatically, like for example a field related to the Department user, so through Javascript we prepopulate that field. Can I do that with the document properties? Also I've read that Quick part only works with Word, what happens with the other types of documents: excel, porwerpoint, publisher?